# Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php

Estou com problema em um cód. que tem como função retornar a pesquisa de uma palavra-chave de um registro do banco.

Erro: **Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given**

Testei no banco MySql, e não tive problema, mas o banco que preciso usar é o sqlserver.

PS: A conexão com o banco está funcionando corretamente.
Cód. conexão com o banco:

```
<?php

// Conexão com banco SqlServer

$servidor = "localhost"; //host
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"dcm_digital", "UID"=>"root", "PWD"=>"root", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");

//Criar conexão 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $connectionInfo);

if($conn){ echo("*** Banco conectado ***<br>"); } else { echo("Conexão falhou.<br>"); die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}
```

Segue o cód. abaixo:

```
<?php

// Include conexão com o bd.
include 'conexaoBD/conexao.php';

$btn     = $_POST['btn'];
$p_chave = $_POST['palavra'];

if(isset($btn)){
    $busca = $p_chave;

    if($busca == null or $busca == " "){

        echo '<center><b>Digite a palavra-chave para pesquisar!</b></center>';

    } else {

        $busca_div = explode(' ',$busca);
        $quant     = count($busca_div);
        $exibe_id  = array("");

        for($i=0; $i<$quant; $i++){

            $pesquisa = $busca_div[$i]; 

            //Banco SqlServer
            $_sql = "SELECT * FROM conteudo_dcm WHERE DCM_conteudo LIKE '%$pesquisa%';";
            $sql  = sqlsrv_query($conn,$_sql);
            $quant_cmps = sqlsrv_num_rows($sql);


            /*/Banco SqlServer
            $_sql = "SELECT * FROM test.conteudo_dcm WHERE DCM_conteudo LIKE '%$pesquisa%';";
            $sql  = mysqli_query($conn, $_sql);
            $quant_cmps = mysqli_num_rows($sql);*/

            if($quant_cmps == 0){

                echo '<center><b>Nenhum resultado obtido!</b></center>';

            } else {
                //while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                while ($linha = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $id       = $linha['DCM_id'];
                    $nome     = $linha['DCM_nome'];
                    $conteudo = $linha['DCM_conteudo'];

                    if(!array_search($id, $exibe_id)){
                        echo /*'<a href="<?php $_href; ?>">'.*/$nome/*.'</a>'*/."<br><br>".
                             substr($conteudo, 0, 600)."<b> ...</b>".
                             "<br>---------------------<br>";   

                        array_push($exibe_id,$id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Primeira coisa já está nesta linha **$_sql = "SELECT * FROM conteudo_dcm WHERE DCM_conteudo LIKE '%$pesquisa%';";**, o correto é **$_sql = "SELECT * FROM conteudo_dcm WHERE DCM_conteudo LIKE '%$pesquisa%'";** Este ; que está ali poder ser o causador de todo o seu problema, veja se resolveu por favor. Vi que em todas as suas querys você utiliza o ; erroniamente, retire de todos e teste por favor.

Comment: @JaksonFischer mesmo após a alteração, o mesmo erro persiste.

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: [link](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-query.php), acho que isto pode te ajudar.

Comment: O valor de `$conn` está errado, está recebendo um objeto, não tem como saber qual é, o erro está dentro do `conexaoBD/conexao.php`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Coloquei o cód. da conexão com o banco na pergunta.

Comment: Ok, coloca antes do sqlsrv_query isto `var_dump($conn);`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vi que na linha do sqlsrv_query eu tinha colocado uma variável após o $_sql por engano. Retirei essa variável (tb retirei da pergunta) e executei o var_dump e retornou a seguinte mensagem: resource(6) of type (SQL Server Connection) 
  Nenhum resultado obtido!

Comment: O tipo está correto, o erro é o mesmo `sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given`, ou agora ele só não está "entrando" no `while`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Agora só não entra no while.